# Drop Down List Column Length Error

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

I am trying to add an "All" row in my drop down list. I did the same thing with a different drop down list and it worked, but for some reason when I add it to this drop down list it gives me this error:

Cannot set column 'GROUPOWNERSHIP'. The value violates the MaxLength limit of this column.

Group Ownership is the value for the drop down.

This is my code:

```
    If AddAllOption = True Then
        Dim NewRow As DataRow = GroupDataTable.NewRow
        NewRow(0) = "All Departments"
        NewRow(1) = "All Departments"
        GroupDataTable.Rows.InsertAt(NewRow, 0)
    End If
```

Does anyone know why it is giving me this error but it doesn't on the other drop down?

Thanks in advance for your responses

Comment: Try changing the value of MaxLength in the Dataset

Comment: That worked, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increase the DataSet.MaxLength property